# Sqlite Setting Serialized mode throws Exception

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I am trying to create a connection by setting FullMutex mode. This is throwing a SQLiteException - Could not open file db path misuse.

```
_DBConn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), dbpath,SQLite.Net.Interop.SQLiteOpenFlags.FullMutex);
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Does it work without the `FullMutex` flag?

Comment: Yes it works without the flag

Comment: can you please put your error stack here ?

Comment: My exception Message "Could not open database file: dbpath (Misuse)" and stacktrace "at SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection..ctor(ISQLitePlatform sqlitePlatform, String databasePath, SQLiteOpenFlags openFlags, Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks, IBlobSerializer serializer, IDictionary`2 tableMappings, IDictionary`2 extraTypeMappings, IContractResolver resolver)"

Comment: Is this occuring in a multi threaded application or a web application? Does the same issue occur if you create a new console application use the same code causing the issue?

Comment: Multithreaded application UWP app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not specifying mandatory flags (SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY or SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE). You have to specify them.

Modified opening command (assuming db does not exists and have to be created):

```
_DBConn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), dbpath, 
  // optional - if you want to create new db    
  SQLite.Net.Interop.SQLiteOpenFlags.Create |   
  SQLite.Net.Interop.SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | 
  SQLite.Net.Interop.SQLiteOpenFlags.FullMutex);
```

> Full reference:
>       https://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html